# How to remove a specific special character from a string with many types of special characters

Tags: java

I have a string with many types of special characters, but I want to remove only `"` (double quotes).

How can this be done?

Comment: when you are removing a particular character from a string, special characters are no different from normal characters.

Answer (score 5):

```
String s = "Hello \"there\"";
s = s.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library:**

```
String s = "Hello \"world\"";
s=CharMatcher.is('\"').removeFrom(s); // '\"' --> Escape the double quote(") using \
```

Comment: @Tanu:I tried it,it's working for me.Can you tell me in what way it's not working ?

Answer (score 0):

```
String withQuotes    = "I am a \" quote";
String withoutQuotes = withQuotes.replace("\"","");
```